# returning custom fault codes for false functions or end user validation

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I have the need in my application to return and store error messages in the database and return a fault code to the end user.

the reason for this is our first level team will troubleshoot low level issues and can get a bit more of an idea as to what's not working or why the user was given the message

For example if there username or password was incorrect return an error message the the end user

" Your username or password was incorrect - Fault Code E34FHE34 "

this message can be passed to our first level team and they can investigate by looking up that fault code in the database and will return a more in depth message

"the users account was locked due to suspicious activity this can be resolved by bla bla bal"

i have a few functions that would execute the above however how can i return  false and a fault code from the function UserLogin() at the same time

alternately is there any other methods to achieve the same thing

Fault Code Generator

```
function CustomUserMessage()
{
// some error message to be stored in the DB and return a fault code to user
echo "Fault Code : E34FHE34";
}
```

Function to process login

```
function UserLogin($username,$password)
 {
 if(empty($username)){return false;}
 elseif(empty($password)){return false;}
 else{return true;}
 }
```

check if function is true or false

```
if( UserLogin("bob@bob.com","") )
{
//process user login
}
else
{
echo "Username or Password Is Incorrect "
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. Maybe have a look at PHP exception handing? http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: how can i return false from the UserLogin() function and pass a string with false

Comment: return an array that has a true/false element and a message element.

Comment: would you happen to have some example code